# Insert margin between table rows

Tags: html, css, html-table, margin

I want to insert a table between two `<tr>` in a `<table>`. I've tried sticking a `<span>` with margin between the rows, I've tried styling the `<tr>` with a class and then adding a margin, nothing.

```
      <tr>
        <td class="near">
          <a href="../index.html" class="near_place">
              <img src="../images.jpeg" width="80" height="60" class="related_photo" />
              <span class="related_info">asdfadfadfaf</span>
          </a>
          </td>
        <td class="near">
          <a class="near_place">
              <img class="related_photo" />
              <h4 class="nearby"></h4>
              <span class="related_info"></span>
          </a>
          </td>
        <td class="near">
          <a class="near_place">
              <img class="related_photo" />
              <h4 class="nearby"></h4>
              <span class="related_info"></span>
          </a>
          </td>
        <td class="near">
          <a class="near_place">
              <img class="related_photo" />
              <h4 class="nearby"></h4>
              <span class="related_info"></span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="near">
          <a href="../index.html"class="near_place">
              <img class="related_photo" />
              <h4 class="nearby"> adfadfad </h4>
              <span class="related_info">asdfadfadfaf</span>
          </a>
          </td>
        <td class="near">
          <a class="near_place">
              <img class="related_photo" />
              <h4 class="nearby"></h4>
              <span class="related_info"></span>
          </a>
          </td>
        <td class="near">
          <a class="near_place">
              <img class="related_photo" />
              <h4 class="nearby"></h4>
              <span class="related_info"></span>
          </a>
          </td>
        <td class="near">
          <a class="near_place">
              <img class="related_photo" />
              <h4 class="nearby"></h4>
              <span class="related_info"></span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

I want like a 20px space between the first `<tr>` and the second.

Comment: Do you have to keep this as one table?  If you made it two tables you could add margin-bottom:20px as a style to the first table.

Comment: perhaps a tr style=height:20px" in between?

Comment: thanks to all. I used what Doug said, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

that is you need ?

```
<h4 class="nearby" style="margin-top: 20px;"> adfadfad </h4>
```